# Is there a method to get the count of specific set from a column of my table or data? Specific set here means predefined conditions

Tags: mysql, database

I have data that needs to be transformed, I am looking for specific result but not getting the idea to reach the result. I have to measure application workflow for a software. Data is saved as a table, I need to transform it into another table with the expected result.
Sample table in MySQL:

```
**UID** **TimeStamp** **Actions**

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:19:59 AM    A

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:20:00 AM    B

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:20:30 AM    C

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:20:32 AM    D

 Usr12    1/8/2019 8:20:59 PM    A

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:20:59 PM    A

 Usr12    1/8/2019 8:21:01 PM    D

 Usr10    1/8/2019 8:21:01 PM    D
```

Here **A, B, C, D are aliases for actions; Open as A, write as B, Headers/style as C, Close as D**

I also have actions set: **open-->close, open-->write, and write-->Headers/style**, this is essentially similar to A-->D, A-->B,B-->C.

What I need is another table that looks similar to this:

**Start_action** **End_action** **Count**

```
   A              B           5000
   B              C           1000
   A              D           2000
```

**count** here represents the number of work flow or actions set by each user. For example if a user did open-->close then Start_action is A and End_action is D and will be counted as one action set/work flow.

I have tried to do this in SQL but not sure how to approach it.